# How to use output PWM in AVR

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, avr, avr-gcc

I have this code to blink an array (8-led) of led one after one:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/delay.h>

#define dela 500

int main (void)
{
    DDRC = 0xFF;
    for(int i=0; ; i++,i%=8)
    {
        PORTC |=(1<<i);
        delay_ms(dela);
        PORTC &= ~(1 << i);
        delay_ms(dela);
    }
}
```

**I want to light up those led partially, like dimmed version of this, something like PWM**

Now my question is how can I do that, how can I write analog output ?

Micro-controller : *ATmega8A* - *PDIP*

Comment: you would require a DAC for analog output ... that is different from PWM ... an analog output is not necessary for varying the brightness of an LED  ... a PWM signal is preferrable because it does not involve analog voltage levels

Comment: Have you considered using larger resistors? You only need one resistor since there will only be one running at a time.

Comment: If you want to minimize software overhead, I would recommend getting a 3-to-8 decoder like the [74HC138](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc138.pdf) and connecting the PWM out to one of the enable lines. This would require only four pins and greatly reduce software overhead.

Comment: PWM is solved , I just need how can I write `analogWrite()` like thing in avr as in arduino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modulate the LED "on" time.

Something like this.

```
for(int i=0; ; i++,i%=8)
{
    for(int k=0; k<26; k++)
    {
        PORTC |=(1<<i);
        delay_ms(10);
        PORTC &= ~(1 << i);
        delay_ms(10);
    }
    delay_ms(dela);
}
```

Comment: I couldn't find any usage of `k`, What i want is like instead of output `true` of `false`, *setting* or *resetting*,*0 volt* or *5 volt*. I want to write an analog output.

Comment: what does this mean? ... `I couldn't find any usage of k`

Comment: You are using `k` in the loop and iterating 25 times. And then using the old code, no usage of `k`. So will it actually dim the light? I haven't tested yet.

Comment: Now I have got it after testing it.. Can you edit the answer and help me with the `analogWrite()` type thing

Comment: that is a different question ... post another question

Comment: `k` is actually "used" two times in the `for` loop .... it is incremented and it is compared to 26